# Resolve all implementation/services of a type using .Net Core DI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am working on migration from Asp.Net MVC to .Net Core.

In my MVC project we used `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` to resolve dependencies which I am trying to replace with .Net Core `IServiceProvider`

However there is one method provided by `IDependencyResolver` which I am not sure if has any replacement in .Net Core.

```
IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType);
```

This is from `Sytem.Web.Mvc` which I believe gets all the dependencies of any type.

I can't find any such method in `IServiceProvider` in .Net Core.

Have you come across any such Api?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See duplicate for an extension method in the package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`: `IEnumerable<object> GetServices(this IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)`.

Comment: The linked duplicate is incorrect as it doesn't deal with the question of how to get all implementations implementing a interface, but rather about how to get all interfaces/implementations.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you, I will test if this works.

Comment: The `ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices(this IServiceProvider, Type)` method has the same signature and behavior of that of `IDependencyResolver.GetServies`.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolve IEnumerable of service type.

Comment: I didn't get it, GetService method only accepts a type and returns single type, Can you show in code?

Comment: CodeCaster’s comment is same as what I meant here. Try that method and pass interface type in.

Comment: Ok. Will test that.